# CLOC diff (count line of code) with git header

Tags: git, diff, cloc

im trying to check lines of code using diff in the git repository with last commit and HEAD, but there's an error showing up,

$ cloc -- diff 182712379cae1b953c5976854e735134530e8241 HEAD

> Error:
>
> 0 text files.
>
> 0 text files.
>
> 0 files ignored.
>
> 2 errors:
>   Unable to read:  182712379cae1b953c5976854e735134530e8241
>
> Unable to read:  HEAD
>
> Nothing to count.

Answer (score 5):

Both `--git` and `--diff`:

`cloc --git --diff 18271237 HEAD`

Comment: Please edit your existing answer instead of adding a new one.

Comment: im still getting the same error `unknown option: git`, 
im trying to get fist commit hash and `HEAD` difference in the repository, using the following, `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` then `182712379cae1b953c5976854e735134530e8241`

Comment: Which version of cloc (``cloc --version``)?  The ``--git`` option has been available for at lest a year.

Comment: @Sadzone: you'll need to get a newer version of cloc (from https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/releases).  v1.78 has a git related bug so maybe try 1.76.  I plan to release 1.80 tomorrow if I have enough time.

Comment: @AlDanial I have updated the version of cloc 1.78, and it did work well, looking forward to seeing your newer version of cloc. thank you. really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just released 1.80.  If you encounter any problems with it please post an issue on the cloc github page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the `--git` switch otherwise cloc will think `HEAD` is the name of a file or directory.

Comment: should I insert cloc --git instead of cloc --diff ??? if i entered cloc --git i do get an error 

unknown option: git